# Is there a way to access debugging information from a script in node.js and/or javascript in general?

Tags: javascript, node.js

While debugging, the debugger (e.g. firebug, chrome's dev tools, or node.js's debugging infrastructure) has information about the entire stack, including variable values, the functions being called, etc. I'm curious to know if that information can be accessed programmatically by any script/process. I'm especially keen to know if it can be done by the script/process being debugged itself.

Thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

Javascript provides most of this information already, but a lot of it is recommended against (because it kills nearly all optimizations V8 and other engines can perform on your code).

Stack: `new Error().stack`

Variables: Simply read the values? (You can even do things like `Object.keys(this)` if you don't know what variables have been attached to your scope. [No way to access closure variables automatically that I'm aware of, though])

Functions: `Function.caller` and `arguments.callee` provide this information.

Again, all of this is killer on your code performance, so I'd avoid doing it whenever possible.

Comment: Simply reading the variables is great if its in scope. What I want to do is read variables from somewhere higher on the stack.